# The correct place to set the UINavigationController's back button title

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, viewdidload

I'm a bit confused with setting the title of navigation item's back button. Usual this is done in the `viewDidLoad` but in my case the view controller is created without the view being loaded. On startup, I'm restoring the view controller hierarchy and pushing view controllers to the navigation controller and only the top view controller's view is loaded. Since the previous view controller's view isn't loaded, I can't use `viewDidLoad` to set the back button's title.

The other thing I'm wondering if I restore the hierarchy the right way. I have pretty similar implementation to the Apple's DrillDownSave example.

The view controller is created programmatically, so `awakeFromNib` shouldn't work either. What is the right place for setting up the back button (and the title)?

Comment: I am not entirely sure about the situation, but I thought viewDidLoad would be called once in any case and that the title would "stick" if it was set.
Maybe you can access it in the view hierarchy and set the title that way? (since it's already loaded I think this should work).
Or you could try setting it in the viewDidAppear / willAppear. Might need to "reset" it though.. with: [yourView viewDidAppear:NO]; (to have viewDidAppear trigger again).

Comment: Yes, the title would stick if `viewDidLoad` was called. The way the navigation stack is built in my case does not call it even once for the view controllers that are stacked under the topmost view controller. `awakeFromNib` would work and so would the `init` methods. I might go for the `init` but I'm really not sure if that's ok.

Comment: An init or custom init should do I suppose. Any reason it should not? Curiosity.. How do you load them without invoking viewDidLoad? Are you using [super loadView] ? Try calling viewDidLoad manually?

Comment: I'm pushing multiple views at once, so only the foremost view will be loaded. I'm doing this at app start up to restore the previous state. I'm a bit insecure to add it to the `init` since I'm referencing the `navigationItem` of the view controller and it has to exist. But I guess that it's ok if it works.